# Discord OAuth2 getting user roles from exact guild

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, discord, discord.js

I am using discord `OAuth2` for chrome extension authentication. I get user `access_token` and would like to use it to get roles of actual user on my server. I tried to use `https://discordapp.com/api/v6/users/@me/` or `https://discordapp.com/api/v6/users/@me/guilds` but it only gives me information about user servers. Can I get information about roles of this user also? How can I do it?

Comment: Not really sure but try https://discordapp.com/api/v6/guilds/<guild_id>/members/<member_id>/roles

Comment: @MalikLahlou I tried but got only `401: Unauthorized` , I think this one is for bots

Comment: What scopes are you using?

Comment: @NotTrixxie identify and guilds

Answer (score 4):

You can access the role **ids** through the [/users/@me/guilds/{guild.id}/member](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user#get-current-user-guild-member) API with the `guilds.members.read` scope and `OAuth2` but don't think you can get the actual role object.  I thought I could call [/guilds/{guild.id}/roles](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#get-guild-roles) to get a list of the roles and resolve the id but this [thread](https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/issues/1008) suggests that its only available to bots and not `OAuth2`.

**EDIT:**
In my scrambling to figure out how to resolve role_ids I found that you can use the shortcut `<@&[role_id]>` in a Discord Message entry form to figure out the name of the role the role_id is actually referring to.

Comment: /users/@me/guilds/{guild.id}/member -- this worked for me perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: hey @caseinc, could you please explain the `<@&[role_id]>`  part of you answer. Were you able to get the role names from the Discord API using oauth2?

Comment: If you have a single server/role you're working with, when you're in the server you can type <@&123123> and the dialog will automatically change it to @ROLE_NAME, so you will know that 123123 means ROLE_NAME. It's not a programmatic way to get role names, but works for simple one-off cases.

Answer (score 0):

To get information about guilds that the user is on and the roles that user is on, you might need to look into Discord's documentation. I'm not 100% sure if you can get information about user's roles through `OAuth2` but this is what I found.

**[guilds](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user#get-current-user-guilds)** scope returns partial guild info

> allows /users/@me/guilds to return **basic information** about all of a user's guilds

Like said on the document (quote on above), it returns **basic information**, this might not include user's roles, but only all guild roles, and not the roles user has.

```json
{
  "id": "80351110224678912",
  "name": "1337 Krew",
  "icon": "8342729096ea3675442027381ff50dfe",
  "owner": true,
  "permissions": "36953089",
  "features": ["COMMUNITY", "NEWS"]
}
```

Not sure if the `guilds` scope return more info than that like [full guild structure](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#guild-object)

I would suggest echoing/logging down information that you get from that scope.

Comment: I did that exactly and that is why I wrote that question :)